# Counting words inside paragraph, where it has HTML tags inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was searching for how to count words in some element, and i successfully got it as following:

```js
var text = $("p").text();

// split() deals with multiple spaces, tabs and new lines.
var wordsCount = text.trim().split( /\s+/ ).length;

$("p").append("<br>Words: <b> " + wordsCount + "</b>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="p-1">These are some texts just for demo purpose</p>
```

But if the paragraph has HTML tags inside like the following:

```
<p class="p-1">These are <span>some texts</span> just for demo purpose</p>
```

or

```
<p class="p-1">These are <span>some <strong>texts</strong></span> just for demo purpose</p>
```

Then it will assume that `<span>some` is single string, although it should count `some` as the 3rd word.

Also for example how to wrap the 3rd or 4th word with span depending on the counting i'm asking for?

Comment: `.text()` does not return html... so what is the problem?

Comment: Well, so how to wrap 3rd or 4th word with span?

Comment: Not sure what you want so I do not know how to answer.

Comment: For the last mention code paragraph, i actually want to wrap each word with span tag. I'm not professional with javascript and jquery, sorry for that. But i searched around until i succeeded to wrap each word with span in case the paragraph don't has html tags inside. But when it has html tags inside, it's going mess. Check this: http://codepen.io/moradxd/pen/PpKdGV

Comment: There is NO easy way to do it if you want to keep track of the other html tags inside. Do you still need the strong and span tags?

Comment: Yes i want to keep any HTML tags inside as it is.

Comment: Is this not possible?

Comment: Whoa. What does counting the words in a paragraph have to do with adding spans on every word? That feels like completely off topic for this question.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet .. You can forgot the counting point. What i want is to wrap each word with for example span tag.

Comment: Ok. So mark the answer here that fixed your problem, and ask another question. You do understand that's two separate questions, right?

Comment: Yes that's right! I'm sorry for that @jdmdevdotnet I will prepare it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/mrquebec13/pen/yMoRez) or if you prefer:

```js
 $('p').each(function(i, element) {
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.split(/\s+/g).map(function(word) {
      return '<span>'+word+'</span>';
  }).join(' ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="p-1">These are some texts just for demo purpose</p>
<p class="p-1">These are <span>some texts</span> just for demo purpose</p>
<p class="p-1">These are <span>some <strong>texts</strong></span> just for demo purpose</p>
```

Or this depending on what you want exactly:

```js
 $("p").each(function(i, element) {
  var text = element.innerHTML;

  // split() deals with multiple spaces, tabs and new lines.
  var wordsCount = text.trim().split( /\w+/ ).length -1;

  element.innerHTML += "<br>Words: <b> " + wordsCount + "</b>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="p-1">These are some texts just for demo purpose</p>
<p class="p-1">These are <span>some texts</span> just for demo purpose</p>
<p class="p-1">These are <span>some <strong>texts</strong></span> just for demo purpose</p>
```

Comment: You did it almost, i appreciate that! But look at this: http://codepen.io/moradxd/pen/bqrmJY I have added `class="woooord"` to make differentiatio. I actually want the wrapping to be around the previewed words. If you checked the the link, you will find that the wrapping is around `2222 3333` and the `2222` is not wrapped, but `3333` is wrapped. I want only the 4 words appear in the preview to be wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .contents() jquery method

[jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

This is a litle example

```
    $( "p" )
  .contents()
  .filter(function(){
    console.log($(this))
    var wordsCount = $(this).text().trim().split( /\s+/ ).length;

$("p").append("<br>Words: <b> " + wordsCount + "</b>");
    return this.nodeType !== 1;
  })
```

[jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/gs9er185/)

```js
$( "p" )
  .contents()
  .filter(function(){
   console.log($(this))
    var wordsCount = $(this).text().trim().split( /\s+/ ).length;

$("p").append("<br>Words: <b> " + wordsCount + "</b>");
    return this.nodeType !== 1;
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="p-1">These are <span>some <strong>texts</strong></span> just for demo purpose</p>
```

Comment: Do you have some way to wrap every word with some HTML tag? I found some way to do that successfully when it don't have HTML tags inside. But if it has HTML tags inside, it's going mess. Check this: http://codepen.io/moradxd/pen/PpKdGV .. You can remove the inside HTML tags and you will find it works correctly.

Comment: Well I made some changes to the script check for the example https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/gs9er185/4/